# Hi there, I'm unable to solve this question. I know that Bayesian is used to solve this question but i don't know where to start

Tags: self-study, bayesian

**Question**
A screening test for a disease shows a positive result in 88 % of all cases when the disease is actually present and in 1 % of all cases when it is not . If a result is positive , the test is repeated . Assume that the second test is independent of the first test . If the prevalence of the disease is 1 in 350 and an individual tests positive twice , what is the probability that the actually has the disease

Tried to solve but seems like this is wrong.
[image][image]

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Please also come up with a more descriptive title.

Comment: Hi I'm unable to solve this question

Answer (score 1):

Your scanned answer correctly derives the probability that a single test is positive. Now, you primarily need to consider how the probability of having two positive tests differs, and then you apply the same formula just with $P(\text{two positive tests}|F_1)$ and $P(\text{two positive tests}|F_2)$ instead of $P(A|F_1)$ and $P(A|F_2)$.

Without additional assumptions, you would not necessarily know how the probability of two positive tests relates to the probability of a single positive test (other than it must be lower), because e.g. tests might have a tendency to be wrong in the same way for the same person on repeated use. However, in your question you are told to assume that the two tests are independent, which simplifies things a lot.

Comment: Hi thank you it was helpful